# In what way are SGD and the Perceptron learning algorithm very similar?

Tags: stochastic-gradient-descent, perceptron

I'm reading [Hands-On Machine Learning](https://www.google.com/search?q=handson+machine+laenring&oq=handson+machine+laenring&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and the author states that:

> You may have noticed the fact that the Perceptron learning algorithm strongly resembles Stochastic Gradient Descent. In fact, Scikit-Learn’s Perceptron class is equivalent to using an SGDClassifier with the following hyperparameters: loss="perceptron", learning_rate="constant", eta0=1 (the learning rate), and penalty=None (no regularization).

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: Maybe tell us what you already know and what is unclear for you?

Answer (score 1):

Both perceptron learning and SGD involve partial derivatives of values of an objective function (SGD) or prediction-error (perceptron) with respect to coefficients. Both problems are essentially solved iteratively via an updating scheme.  Both cases are also function minimization procedures.  Independent of perceptron learning, derivates don't have to be employed, since one can use finite differencing, or e.g., the Gauss-Siedel method.

Comment: What you say here is also true of batch gradient descent. I don't think you've touched on the crucial similarity, though. Everything is the same, except that perceptron uses [error-driven updates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error-driven_learning) and traditionally assumes a learning rate of 1.